# Options for Syncing iPhone App with Desktop Application

Tags: windows, iphone, macos, itunes

What are the options for syncing an iPhone App's data with that of a Desktop application on either Mac OS X or Windows.

So far I have come up with:

1. iTunes plugin (Windows and Mac OS X)
2. iSync (Mac OS X only)
3. The "Cloud"

Answer (score 2):

You could sync directly via wifi. Bento, for example, allows you to sync from within the Bento iPhone app to the Desktop app over wifi.